# ionic - send push notification to Firebase from Ionic device

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can you give me an example how to send notification to Firebase server from Ionic device?

I tried some codes and I getting error like :

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send 401 ()
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot send notifications from one device directly to another device. Sending messages *to* a device requires the use of a server key, which (as its name implies) should only be present on a server (in a process you control). For one approach of sending device-to-device notifications through a server, see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html. The article is written for Android, but the same approach can be applied across all platforms.

Comment: I mean to send notification from device to server (firebase) and the target is another some users. Take "chat" to example, I want that if someone react in specific chat, another users that react in this chat will receive a notifiaction.